# When client request a IP address from DHCP server, why does it also use ARP?

Tags: networking

When I use Wireshark to observe the process of the DHCP process, I noticed that the server also use ARP broadcast a message? I want to know what the use of this message. Like it shows on the screenshot, the broadcast message ask who has the IP 192.168.0.1.
[the screenshot of Wireshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kck7P.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARP Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521102/arp-communication)

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming. This question belongs on one of the SE sites for networking.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, DHCP server is configured to execute ARP before offering an IP address to a DHCP client to ensure that IP address has not been allocated to another client on the network. Because there may be several DHCP servers in the same network